# Help me decide in a location for my raised bed garden

Tags: soil, raised-beds, blackberry, ph

I'm building a 6x3 raised bed in my brooklyn ny backyard however, i wanted to know if i set it up at the left side it would be half under a mulberry/blackberry tree and the right side it would be in full sun but no berries falling on it. 
So my question is whats better choice?
having berries falling (when in season) on the vegetable garden & in partial shade.
Or full sun & no berries, if that's even an issue.
Please let me know the pros n cons on each scenario.

Thanks a ton guys.

I'll post pictures tonight or tomorrow of the yard

Comment: You could actually pick the mulberries and eat them, rather than letting them drop to the ground. If you are letting them drop to the ground you could gather them and add to compost. Shade is bad for vegetable gardens in the NYC latitude. You'll want all the sun you can get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Full sun - most vegetables like as much sun as possible, although in very, very hot countries, some shade from the midday sun may be beneficial.The berries falling doesn't matter either way, but they'll be a pain to pick up.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest going with full sun.  Most vegetables you grow will need full sun.  I am talking from personal experience and have 3 raised beds on the sunny side of the house in California.  I don't think mulberries are issues but I don't have them or anything above.  I prefer not having anything drop in my vegetable patch and like it to be clean and clear